# Differences between case object T and case class T() when defining ADT?

Tags: scala, singleton, algebraic-data-types

Let's say in scala I have an ADT as follows:

```
sealed trait Animal

object Animal {
case class Lion(name: String)    extends Animal
case class Elephant(name:String) extends Animal
case object Tiger                extends Animal
}
```

Here, is it preferable to declare `Tiger` as a case object or should it be declared as an empty case class i.e `case class Tiger()` ? Does one have any advantage over other?

Answer (score 4):

If there is the only `Tiger` it should be an object. If there can be several equal `Tiger`s it should be a class.

```
val tiger = Tiger()
val tiger1 = Tiger()
tiger == tiger1 // true
tiger eq tiger1 // false
```

Comment: Worth saying that even if there are multiple tigers, if they are all equal, then there is no difference in just using a case object, since using `eq` with case classes barely makes sense IMHO. - Also, it would be good to add that all those should be `final`

Answer (score 2):

My two cents: I think if you would like to declare empty `case class` like `Tiger` in your case - stop and think, because it highly likely you are doing something wrong.

Case classes were designed for easy work with structured data - but if there is no data declared in case class, it is unclear how it should be interpreted from the business logic point of view. On the other hand - `case object` clearly describes certain type of signal, which does not need any additional data, because it singleton.

I'd propose a bit practical example:

```
/**
* Sum type describing abstract operation over some user profile in theoretical social network
*/
sealed trait UserProfileOperation

/**
* User requests edit certain field with value in it's profile
*/
case class Edit(field: String, value: String) extends UserProfileOperation 

/**
* User requests to delete own profile - no additional data required, 
* so it is always singleton type signal
*/
case object Delete extends UserProfileOperation
```

Hope this helps!