# Pattern matching custom implementation of List ADT

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I understand (kind of) how pattern matching works in Scala,
Let's say I have two lists of the form:

```
  sealed abstract class IntList
  case class Empty()                        extends IntList // The empty list, often called Nils
  case class Element(n: Int, tail: IntList) extends IntList // Element is usually called Cons
```

Let's say I want to create the function `take(n, xs)`

- It should return the first n elements of xs.

I tried with normal pattern matching:

```
  def take(n: Int, xs: IntList): IntList = xs match {
    case n == 0 => Empty()
    case xs : Empty => Empty() 
    case xs : Element => Element(xs.n, take(n-1, xs))
  }
```

But then of course, n is not recognised,  `error: not found: value == case n == 0 => Empty()`

How can I do this, it is probably simple but I am a beginner in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the first case where it should be

```
case _ if n == 0 => Empty()
```

and a bug in third case where you forgot to pass the `tail`

```
case xs: Element => Element(xs.n, take(n-1, xs.tail))
```

Try

```
sealed trait IntList
case object Empty extends IntList
case class Element(n: Int, tail: IntList) extends IntList

def take(n: Int, xs: IntList): IntList = xs match {
  case _ if n == 0 => Empty
  case Empty => Empty
  case Element(n, tail) => Element(n, take(n-1, tail))
}

val list = Element(1, Element(2, Element(3, Empty)))
take(2, list)   // res0: IntList = Element(1,Element(2,Empty))
```

Consider `case object` instead of `case class Empty()` when there is no data as per [Differences between case object T and case class T() when defining ADT?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60137014/5205022)